# Pulseaudio build issue in yocto

Tags: embedded-linux, raspberry-pi3, alsa, yocto, pulseaudio

I am using Raspberry Pi 3 model B. I am facing build issue while building bitbake pulseaudio. Please find my configuration details:

1. Yocto : Jethro branch
2. pulseaudio.inc RDEPENDS_pulseaudio-server +=
   "alsa-plugins-pulseaudio-conf"
3. we are using alsa-plugins_1.0.29.bb
4. bitbake pulseaudio

> ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'alsa-plugins-pulseaudio-conf' (but /home/guest/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-multimedia/pulseaudio/pulseaudio_6.0.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
>
> NOTE: Runtime target 'alsa-plugins-pulseaudio-conf' is unbuildable, removing...
> Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['alsa-plugins-pulseaudio-conf']
> ERROR: Required build target 'pulseaudio' has no buildable providers.
> Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['pulseaudio', 'alsa-plugins-pulseaudio-conf']

Comment: Add alsa-plugins to IMAGE_INSTALL.

Comment: aswanth, that won't help. The correct package would already go into the image (because or RDEPENDS) but the build system can't figure out how to build it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the recipe the package alsa-plugins-pulseaudio-conf is generated if "pulseaudio" is in the alsa-plugins PACKAGECONFIG. By default that happens if your DISTRO_FEATURES includes "pulseaudio".

So check your DISTRO_FEATURES, ensure "pulseaudio" is in there (and make sure you don't modify the alsa-plugins PACKAGECONFIG in a bad way).

To see what your DISTRO_FEATURES contains:

```
bitbake -e pulseaudio |grep "^DISTRO_FEATURES="
```

To add pulseaudio if it's not there right now (you can do this in local or distro config):

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " pulseaudio "
```

The whitespace preceding the feature name is required.

To check what PACKAGECONFIG is getting used for alsa-plugins (this should contain "pulseaudio"):

```
bitbake -e alsa-plugins|grep "^PACKAGECONFIG="
```

Comment: Thank You very much....
i tried what you said in 3 ways,
1) I tried removing pulseaudio from DISTRO_FEATURES using
**DISTRO_FEATURES_REMOVE = "pulseaudio"** 
in the local.conf file. But still i get the same error message as before
2) I also tried adding pulseaudio
**DISTRO_FEATURES = "pulseaudio"** in the same local.conf
it also shows the same error
and 
3) I tried commenting out the entire DISTRO_FEATURES statement in local.conf
which also reproduces the same error.
what can i do further ? It would be great if you can help me out

Comment: Don't overwrite DISTRO_FEATURES or remove things from it, just make sure it has "pulseaudio" in it. I'll edit the answer a little...

Comment: Thank you so much for your input, i have made the changes u suggested and i were able to succesfully pass through the error and pulseaudio started building.  But while building it lead to do compile error as follows  


I am getting an r7 error                                                              **/pulseaudio/6.0-r0/pulseaudio-6.0/src/pulsecore/remap_neon.c:65:1: error: r7 cannot be used in asm here**                                                         please share your inputs! Thank you in advance